# login to website and fetch data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to retrieve the data from a website after the script successfully logs in. I am able to fetch the data from the website but it seems it just giving me the information from the website prior to the website of the login. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a software to fetch data of a site after login, you might have to handle sessions and cookies as that's how a site knows a user if logged in or not.

Comment: that sounds exactly what I would want to do, any ideas on how to do it? or any links where I can find info about it?